# Intellij Datagrip IDE Oracle Linux Not Storing Data Source

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea, datagrip

In Intellij Datagrip, when adding a new datasource(Oracle DB) it is expected to save the settings of the database so when restarting the IDE, the settings will be there to easily connect.

Recently I encounter a strange error on "Failed to save settings. Please restart DataGrip". While I have tried to restart datagrip and restart the operating system(Parrot OS), same issue. I also tried to check the logs however no fruitful description.

Additionally, after adding the datasource, and checking the routines (functions, procedures of the Oracle Database) Datagrip does not display the full code as it did in other Operating Systems. Rather displays the following "-- Missing Source Code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the missing code is probably the result of a known major bug of Datagrip, due to changes made to its introspector architecture, when Jetbrains introduced the three levels of introspection for Oracle databases. You can be informed about the issue or participate by visiting the links
[here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-14931/Introspection-does-not-work-correctly-Unable-to-get-package-body) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15100/Oracle-Database-19c-EE-Introspection-failure-Results-might-be-in).

As for the problem of not being able to save settings and datasources, although it is impossible to know for sure what the problem is, without looking at the logs, you can try to check if something has changed in your user's permissions or groups, and if not, you can try renaming the directory of the application's data, so that a new directory with the default settings can be created, to see if the problem persists or not.

Comment: Thanks alot, I run datagrip with elevated privileges and it worked. This includes with saving a connection and displaying of source code.